# AngularJS view build for RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

Angular has great view injection for .html partials but its not optimal performance-wise for production.

I've seen some directives like angularui use template caching like:

```
 angular.module("template/alert/alert.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/alert/alert.html",
   "<div class='alert' ng-class='\"alert-\" + (type || \"warning\")'>\n" +
   "<button ng-show='closeable' type='button' class='close' ng-click='close()'>&times;</button>\n" +
   "<div ng-transclude></div>\n" +
   "</div>\n" +
   "");
}]);
```

Is there a build process for things for grunt or requirejs where you could do something like:

```
   // ngview will be used in production 
   // mode to map view dependencies but 
   // not used in development mode
   define(['myapp', 'ngview!home'], function(){ ... });
```

then in built file it would produce the templateCache object.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While its not specific to Require, there is a task for grunt called [html2js](https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js)